# regular expression in django 2.0.1

Tags: django, python-3.x, regular-language

```
re_path(r'^(<int:album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.view_details, name='view_details')
```

Why I am getting errors? How to write this regular expression in django version 2.0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path('<int:album_id>',views.view_details, name='view_details')
```

or with `re_path`

```
re_path('(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/', views.view_details, name='view_details'),
```

Comment: but when i wite something like this                                                           're_path('(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/favorite/', views.view_details, name='view_details'),'    it is not working

Answer (score 1):

make sure that main urls.py

```
path('music/', include('music.urls')),
```

make sure that music.urls.py

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
re_path(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```